# Java where to put private assets?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know in which folder can I put private assets such as SASS files ?
Is `src/main/resources` fine ?

Comment: What do you mean by _private_?

Comment: Not accessible by something else than the web server

Comment: `resources` is good. Anything that ends up under `WEB-INF` is safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the files that should be protected and not being able to access directly in a web application **must** reside inside WEB-INF lib or in a folder inside it (regardless the frameworks you use, like Spring).

Note that all resources inside the src/main/resources folder will be copied to WEB-INF/classes folder, so there's nothing wrong about putting these resources there.

Comment: I *think* my edit to your second paragraph made things more clear and I'm hoping they're correct.  Let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: @tieTYT in my second paragraph I meant to say that when you compile the java classes (.class files) are put inside WEB-INF/classes, so even if you put your resources as part as your sources (which would be odd), they will be copied inside WEB-INF and safe for any external malicious user.

Comment: But by default, I don't think anything but .java classes are copied over from src/main/java.  EG: If you put a .xml file in there, by default it won't be copied over.

Comment: @tieTYT it is copied.

Comment: For files that need even more security (such as login credentials), it may be a good idea to keep them entirely separate -- not in the source code at all, not checked in, etc -- and read them from some predetermined place, like `~/.yourappname/config.properties`. I don't know if that'll work for your web app/framework specifically.

Comment: @yshavit in fact, those kind of resources should be outside the web application domain :).

Comment: I just tried it.  It's not copied.  Only java files are copied from the java folder.

Comment: @tieTYT that's strange. Well, it may be maven behavior, I have to do some tests after this :)

Comment: I used a file name foo.xml in my "src/main/java" folder.  FYI, you can override these defaults by saying that "src/main/java" is a resource folder.  I DO NOT recommend this, but it's useful to know if you're trying to migrate an app *to* maven.